# Narrow SomeType vs SomeType[]

Tags: typescript, narrowing

I can easily use a constant string value to narrow down a union type:

```
type Payload1 = { /* ... arbitrary type ... */ };
type Payload2 = { /* ... arbitrary type ... */ };
type T1 = { type: 'type1', payload: Payload1 }
type T2 = { type: 'type2', payload: Payload2 }
type T = T1 | T2;

const fn = (value: T) => {

    if (value.type === 'type1') {
        value; // Typescript knows `value is T1`
    }

    if (value.type === 'type2') {
        value; // Typescript knows `value is T2`
    }

};
```

Here there are only two cases:

1. `value.type` is the constant `"type1"`
2. `value.type` is the constant `"type2"`

But what if I expand `T`, allowing `payload` to be either a single item or an array? Now there are 4 possibilities:

1. `value.type` is `"type1"` and `value.payload` is *not* an `array`
2. `value.type` is `"type1"` and `value.payload` *is* an `array`
3. `value.type` is `"type2"` and `value.payload` is *not* an `array`
4. `value.type` is `"type2"` and `value.payload` *is* an `array`

Here is an example:

```
type Payload1 = {};
type Payload2 = {};
type T1Single = { type: 'type1', payload: Payload1 }
type T1Batch = { type: 'type1', payload: Payload1[] };
type T2Single = { type: 'type2', payload: Payload2 }
type T2Batch = { type: 'type2', payload: Payload2[] };

// Here's T, now with 4 types instead of 2:
type T = T1Single | T1Batch | T2Single | T2Batch;

const fn = (value: T) => {

    if (value.type === 'type1' && !Array.isArray(value.payload)) {
        value; // Typescript says `value is T1Single | T1Batch`?!
        // How does `T1Batch` remain in the union if `value.payload` isn't an array??
    }

    if (value.type === 'type1' && Array.isArray(value.payload)) {
        value; // Typescript says `value is T1Single | T1Batch`?!
        // How does `T1Single` remain in the union if `value.payload` is an array??
    }

    if (value.type === 'type2' && !Array.isArray(value.payload)) {
        value; // Typescript says `value is T2Single | T2Batch`?!
        // How does `T2Batch` remain in the union if `value.payload` isn't an array??
    }

    if (value.type === 'type2' && Array.isArray(value.payload)) {
        value; // Typescript says `value is T2Single | T2Batch`?!
        // How does `T2Single` remain in the union if `value.payload` is an array??
    }

};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-UHYCHI8EwUzo7GqfHSInEAkU9jM0SSavd-O0nmGe3ma7i81S0hubz+YLhX3a1LToPZbk8qthuoSdlqOp6galwFMOiDmpa462La9qOtGLqUteFSLt6vrLoGZLrmqEZqjuc77siSDHhi4Bnhml5zu6eC3iBUBFuqnKvuWH5VjWrp1n+UQAdBdjAfe7FdhBvb9hE-6wfBY7Wkhk4oTO36uphOjYX6AaroRTLEeG9QRnekCrLIqQVA4IS0OZMoxIx3hpJuWTmfK9nJI5FS1BwJh3A8ArPG82YKHZezyoCxAgqAG47riq7npmV6McxYlsSWZbvpWX7oRKUqheAQHKhuBmMjutEXmSSW5vSLGQGlz4ZRWn7VmplJ1vlhVtvpW6QNZpnkEAA)

**Why is typescript only partially narrowing down the type, and how can I achieve fully narrowed values for the 4 cases?**

EDIT: Looks like multiple conditions in the `if` is irrelevant; typescript struggles to narrow based on `Array.isArray` alone:

```
type Payload = {};
type Single = { payload: Payload }
type Batch = { payload: Payload[] };

const fn = (value: Single | Batch) => {

    if (!Array.isArray(value.payload)) {
        value; // Typescript says `value is Single | Batch`?!
    }

    if (Array.isArray(value.payload)) {
        value; // Typescript says `value is Single | Batch`?!
    }

};
```

Comment: I don't think you can use multiple properties for the discriminant like that when narrowing a union, I think you'd have to have type1-type4. But IDK for sure.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen jcalz link the relevant issues about this before... Something about type predicates not propagating to parent objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to treat `T` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), but the `payload` property is not recognized as a discriminant.  For a property to be seen as a valid discriminant, it must contain unit/[literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  Your `type` property is valid because `"type1"` and `"type2"` are string literal types.  But arrays and your `Payload` types are object types, not literal types.  So you can't check `value.payload` and have it narrow the apparent type of `value` itself.

Note that `Array.isArray(value.payload)` does act as a type guard on the `value.payload` property, but because the property is not a discriminant, this narrowing does not propagate up to `value` itself. There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) to allow property type guards to propagate up to containing objects.  It's not part of the language yet, though, and previous requests for it were declined as it was considered too expensive to synthesize new types for every type guard check on a nested property.

---

For now, if you want to get behavior like this you could write a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that narrows a value based on whether its `payload` property is an array.  Like this:

```
function hasArrayPayload<T extends { payload: any }>(
    value: T): value is Extract<T, { payload: any[] }> {
    return Array.isArray(value.payload)
}
```

Then instead of writing `Array.isArray(value.payload)` inline, you call `hasArrayPayload(value)`:

```
const fn = (value: T) => {
    if (value.type === 'type1' && !hasArrayPayload(value)) {
        value; // (parameter) value: T1Single
    }

    if (value.type === 'type1' && hasArrayPayload(value)) {
        value; // (parameter) value: T1Batch
    }

    if (value.type === 'type2' && !hasArrayPayload(value)) {
        value; // (parameter) value: T2Single
    }

    if (value.type === 'type2' && hasArrayPayload(value)) {
        value; // (parameter) value: T2Batch
    }
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-yJgQ91N9w2Z0258JW233R4lsvoCvz5M+utB1dhuCRjdL9W+I5dkz7xhAA)

Comment: This is really insightful - I had never encountered the concept of "discriminated unions" and this really broadened my understanding! Btw, I extended your function to allows checking any property (not just `payload`) by passing the property name to the function:

`const hasArrayProp = <T, K extends keyof T>(val: T, k: K): val is Extract<T, { [KK in K]: any[] }> => Array.isArray(val[k]);`

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to narrow down the types multiple steps at once.

Instead, you can use type predicates or type guards

For Example:

```js
type Payload1 = { action: string };
type Payload2 = { action: number };
type T1 = { type: "type1"; payload: Payload1 };
type T2 = { type: "type2"; payload: Payload2 };
type T3 = { type: "type1"; payload: Payload1[] };
type T4 = { type: "type2"; payload: Payload2[] };
type T = T1 | T2 | T3 | T4;

const isType1 = (arg: T1 | T2 | T3 | T4): arg is T1 | T3 => {
  return arg.type === "type1";
};
const isTypeArray = <T>(arg: T | T[]): arg is T[] => {
  return Array.isArray(arg);
};
```

Here is a codesandbox link of above example:
[playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-napier-888f79?file=/src/index.ts:0-479)

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question?  `Array.isArray(value.payload)` already acts as a type guard on `value.payload` without the need for your custom `isTypeArray()`.  The issue is that there is no type guard on `value` itself, and that is not accomplished by `isTypeArray()` either.

Comment: I actually don't think there is any issue narrowing multiple types with one `if` condition - as it turned out, the issue I presented in my question was purely related to narrowing the union based on whether a property was an array (see the "EDIT" section of my question for proof!)